# Scan through a mysql table and update a column

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to scan through a table, query inputs from two of its columns, and use those inputs to update another column of the same table.

The way I am doing right now is:
scanning through the table extracting the value:

```
SELECT key, col1,col2 from table1;
```

Then I do an expensive operation for each row:

```
someComputedValue = someComplicatedFunction(col1,col2)
```

And then updating it using another update query

```
Update mytable where primaryKey = key set col3 = someComputedValue
```

Since the table I am dealing with is large, I was wondering if there was some way of just updating the value while scanning it. Essentially just making one query per update call.

**EDIT**: I think I didn,t make myself clear. I am connecting to the database from java, The complicatedFunction is not implementable as a sql function(it IS complicated). It will instead be computed in java. I don't think It is possible to provide a java function in the sql statement( Is it?). This is why I currently have to read the value out of the database and then update it with another statement.

So ideally I would want to do something like this.

> 1. point towards a row in sql table.
> 2. read values out to java variables(while still pointing to the same row)
> 3. update the other column in this row

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
UPDATE mytable SET col3=someComplicatedFunction(col1,col2);
```

It very well might lock up the table until it completes though.  To get around this you can do say, 10 at a time or something via a WHERE clause throttled by something external to the DB though.

Another solution is to create another table (column defs omitted because you didn't specify):

```
START TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE temp (key, col3) SELECT key, someComplicatedFunction(col1,col2) FROM mytable;
UPDATE mytable mt, temp tp SET mt.col3=tp.col3 WHERE mt.key=tp.key;
DROP TABLE temp;
COMMIT;
```

This will do it in two steps, in theory allowing temp to take as long as necessary to create, while only putting a read-lock on mytable (as opposed to the write-lock you would have otherwise).  The actual writing to mytable will be very fast.  The tricky part is that you still can't allow mytable to change during the process, since changes might not be reflected in temp.

EDIT: (The `someComplicatedFunction` must be implemented in Java):

In the simplest form, yes: you just connect, `SELECT`, and foreach result, `UPDATE`.

That will be slow.  Sadly, I don't believe SQL supports callbacks or whatever -- You will need to use a query to get the data and a query to return the data.  However, you can speed things up already by only doing one `SELECT` and iterating through that.  Depending on if `(col1, col2)` is unique, you also *might* be faster by selecting `(col1, col2)`, and updating based on that.

However, your best bet is likely to use the `CASE` syntax:

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET myfield = CASE other_field
        WHEN 1 THEN 'value'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'value'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'value'
    END
WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

So, start with a sting containing `UPDATE mytable SET col3 = CASE key`, and then as you loop through the input (`SELECTED` as `(key, col1, col2)`), calculate `col3`, and add lines saying `"WHEN "+keyval+" THEN "+col3val`.  Also keep a String following the values of `key`: `keystr+=", "+keyval;`. Once you finish going through them all, you just need to add the line `WHERE key IN ("+keystr+");"`.

Thus, you can do a single `SELECT` to get all of the needed rows, followed by Java calculating and building the single `UPDATE` query.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE myTable SET col3 = myFunction(col1, col2) WHERE primaryKey = key
```

Should about get you there.